# Does Google messenger need phone tower signal?

Tags: google-hangouts

If I cannot detect any tower signal but I have wifi at home, will wifi only work? I am currently in this situation and waiting for a message.

Answer (score 1):

Google messenger ? (Hangout) is that what you mean ? it's require an internet connection and that's it .
yes it's require a signal tower if you want to run it on your phone using 3G,2G,4G data connection .

Answer (score 0):

In short, probably not depending on your phone.  Most phones will do everything but make phone calls over the internet.  Some phones, have a Wi-Fi Calling option that allows people to use their wireless internet instead of the cellular towers, reducing usage of cellular signals completely.  Using the towers for non-calls is not necessary for pretty much all of the apps on your phone as they all just need access to the internet and the towers simply provide another means to get onto the internet.  As far as I can tell, all of Google's mainstream apps, (maps, messages, hangouts, mail, etc.) only require internet access, so having your phone on your Wi-Fi should be enough.